# how to send text message

Tags: java, android

I'm a bit confused. I think following API is used to send messages from one instance of the emulator to another. Will it also work on the real phone to send SMS?

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
sm.sendTextMessage(destinationAddress, null, "Hello world", null, null, null);
```

Comment: the concept of emulator is to emulate the android device. Though I have never dealt with SmsManager, I think it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is also working on real devices here `sm.sendTextMessage(destinationAddress, null, "Hello world", null, null, null);` **destinationAddress** must be in quotes like **"1234567890"** and **"Hello world"** will be delivered to the destination number.